# Change php configuration allow_url_include on iis

Tags: php, iis

I have configured php **on iis**, windows server. I need to include a url in program, and I get an error

```
wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

Normally, I would go in the php.ini file and change it. But now, I don't know where to look.

Comment: In the php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP instalation path, and same php.ini

You can try in c:\windows\php.ini also

Or you can phpinfo() to see where the ini is

Comment: phpinfo(); will tell you where it is

Comment: Yes, i was adding that too, but my 3G connection closed on my phone ;). Added